# Spring Security: OAuth 2.0 Login: Bypass login page

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to completely skip login page (default/custom) and directly go to authorization endpoint for authentication:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login/oauth2")
                ...
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .baseUri("/login/oauth2/authorization")
                    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could NOT remove the default/custom login page of spring security but as a work-around I added a redirect on the login page so that the end-user never know that there is a login-page in-between.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/oauth2", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView loginPage() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/oauth2/authorization/google", "model", model);
}
```

Comment: This was more painful to find an answer to than I first hoped :)

Comment: Add `@EnableOAuth2Sso` to this class.