# Bypassing the login page to send the user directly to the authorization URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I'm new to the Spring Framework and I'm trying to set up my application with Spring Security using Azure AD authentication. I have the basics set up and my application correctly authenticates to Azure AD.

The question I have involves bypassing the default "/login" page that gets generated. Instead of landing on the default "/login" page (or creating my own custom one) when authentication is required, I would like the application to automatically redirect to Microsoft's login page.

[image]

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config")
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter')
compile 'com.scireum:parsii:1.5'
compile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:7.0.0.jre8'
compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.3.5"
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

}

WebSecurityConfig class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("Users")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
    }
}
```

[I've tried this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926158/spring-security-oauth-2-0-login-bypass-login-page) by adding ".loginPage("/auth") to the above and added this method into the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView loginPage() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/oauth2/authorization/azure", "model", model);
}
```

That results in this redirect error.

[image: Error]

[I've also tried this](https://vkuzel.com/spring-security-5-oauth-2-0-skip-login-page-in-case-of-only-one-authentication-service-is-configured) but it fails to run.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instance must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ctr.Application.main(Application.java:12) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instance must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instance must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forInstance(ResolvableType.java:1068) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ctr.security.WebSecurityConfig.getSingleAuthenticationUrl(WebSecurityConfig.java:59) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ctr.security.WebSecurityConfig.init(WebSecurityConfig.java:47) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ctr.security.WebSecurityConfig.init(WebSecurityConfig.java:21) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ctr.security.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3561cee5.init(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37d1d0f8.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37d1d0f8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8b7fc73a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37d1d0f8.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

This

```
 at com.ctr.security.WebSecurityConfig.getSingleAuthenticationUrl(WebSecurityConfig.java:59)
```

points to

```
 ResolvableType type = ResolvableType.forInstance(clientRegistrationRepository).as(Iterable.class);
```

I don't know Spring well enough to know what's going on in this example and why it's returning a null value. Is it possible to bypass the login page? Or do I just need live with customizing a login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to bypass the default generated login page and automatically trigger authentication, you need to configure `oauth2Login().loginPage(..)`

For example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/azure")
            ...
}
```

Here is a link to a [sample](https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-protocol-patterns/blob/master/ui-app/src/main/java/sample/config/SecurityConfig.java#L49)

Also, new in Spring Security 5.1, `oauth2Login()` will automatically trigger if you only have 1 `ClientRegistration` configured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will note this for future reference. We ended up investing time in setting up a login page with a redirect link.

`@GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (null == request.getQueryString()) {
            return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/azure";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }`