# the redirection URL in Microsoft Azure is ever to login. How can I change it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

I am using the authentications quickstart of microsoft for spring and it always redirected me to **http://localhost:8080/login**. Even when I specify that I need to access another page for example **http://localhost:8080/secure_page**, whenever I press the login button and start the login process with my microsoft account it redirects me to **http://localhost:8080/login**, what is wrong. someone knows how I can make it redirect me to other pages. I have tried everything but it still doesn't work.
Thank you for your help

this is my application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.*=DEBUG

server.address=localhost
server.port=8080

homePage=http://${server.address}:${server.port}

ssoServiceUrl=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
endSessionEndpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout

security.oauth2.client.client-id=......
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=.....
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid profile
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=header
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form

security.oauth2.issuer=https://login.microsoftonline.com/......./v2.0

security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth2/v2.0/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
aad.msGraphEndpointHost="https://graph.microsoft.com/"

server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
```

when I write "...." it means that it is sensitive data and I have not wrote it for security.
this is my controller class.

```
@Controller
public class SecurePageController {


    @RequestMapping("/secure_page")
    public ModelAndView securePage(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("secure_page");
        return mav;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView indexPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

this one is the index of the example

```
....
<body>
<h3 style="text-align:center;">Authentication</h3>
<br>
<br>
<form style="text-align:center;" action="/secure_page">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

at least this is the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Order(value = 0)
public class AppConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String logoutUrl = env.getProperty("endSessionEndpoint") + "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(env.getProperty("homePage"), "UTF-8");

        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutUrl);
    }
}
```

**The example is working but ever with the false url redirection**. I would appreciate any kind of information because I always get the same result even if in the index I specifically call **/secure_page**, always the url_redirect in the url is **/login** and not **/secure_page**.

Comment: Please check this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623746/bypassing-the-login-page-to-send-the-user-directly-to-the-authorization-uri) it may help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was interesting but it was not what I am looking for, the user there have made a redirection from login to other page because he could not change this Login default redirection. :S I do not see in the Documentation how can i make this. It's a shame that no documentation can be found on something so basic I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Application Administrator rights can change in the Azure Portal.

Azure Active Directory, App Registrations,

You will need to search for your App name

Authentication.

There will be a section for 'Redirect URIs'

Comment: Yes you are right, I have made it, but it is not working yet. because the url, which is called when i pressed the login Button, is yet "Login".
url part="..&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&.." .